# Define snapshot deletion using Jfrog CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, artifactory, jfrog-cli, retention

I am using Artifactory 7.7.3, and I want to define a retention policy for snapshot deletion using JFrog CLI. I want to delete an old snapshot if a new one is deployed. And I am not aware of how to start with it.

Is it like JFrog CLI has to be installed in my Linux machine where my Artifactory is installed? And how do I proceed with it; where do I run the commands?

Answer (score 0):

JFrog CLI does not support defining such a retention policy. You can use it to delete the snapshots manually by path.

I believe [Artifactory User Plugins](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Plugins) is the way to go. You can create your own, or use an existing one like [mavenSnapshotCleanupWhenRelease](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/mavenSnapshotCleanupWhenRelease) or [artifactCleanup](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup).

Another option would be to publish a build after every snapshot, then using [Build Retention](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ControlBuildRetention) with `"count": 1` & `"deleteBuildArtifacts": true`. You can [publish](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-PublishingBuild-Info) the build and [discard](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DiscardingOldBuildsfromArtifactory) it using JFrog CLI.

Comment: Could you please be specific on how can we proceed to delete snapshots using Artifactory plugin in Jenkins ? Like where to mention the maximum snapshots needed kind of details ? And I need 2 snapshots maximum and if 3rd Snapshot gets deployed, the 1st one should gets removed.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/vars-build-retention-example/Jenkinsfile) pipeline example on how to define retention and how to publish build info. If you publish a build after every snapshot, you can modify the maxBuilds accordingly

Comment: Where to mention the artifactory URL in the pipeline ? And if there is a possibility to delete the build using cURL commands, please let me know that as well. Thanks